# Windows Vista Default Printer Changes When Using Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop, printing

I've recently discovered on the Vista boxes in my office that if a user logs in from outside the network using Remote Desktop to their office PC the default printer changes.  That change of default printer is really annoying when they come back to the office and have to reset the default.

Is there some way to set or verify a default when the user logs in locally?

Comment: [Here is a possible related blog entry](http://www.code250.co.uk/blog/stop-the-default-printer-changing-when-using-remote-desktop) when the default printer changes to the local computers default. Go to Admin Tools > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration > Connections > RDP-Tcp > Properties > Client Settings and Check "Default to main client printer". This prevents the printer default changing to the local default printer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If disabling printing through remote desktop is not an option you could create a quick visual basic script to reset the printer, and put it in their startup folder.

```
Option Explicit
Dim oNet
Set oNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
oNet.SetDefaultPrinter "printer name"
```

Comment: That's not a bad work-around!

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that I had to remove the "Option Explicit" line.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I forgot to dim the oNet variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it changing to the one on their home PC? Terminal Server/RDP setting to Disable printer redirection ought to prevent this, I think.